# Analytic continuation of a $p$-adic function

Tags: p-adic-analysis, p-adic-numbers, p-adic

Let $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ and $(b_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ be sequences of $\mathbb Q_p$ such that the function $f:z\in\mathbb Q_p\to\sum_{n\ge0}a_nz^n+b_nz^{n+1}$converges in $\{|z|_p<1\}$. Assume that the series $\sum_{n\ge0}a_n+b_n$ converges in $\mathbb Q_p$. Can the function $f$ be continued in a larger disk in an analytic function?

Thanks in advance for for any hint or answer.

Comment: You are not assuming that $\sum a_nz^n$ and/or $\sum b_nz^n$ converge, right?

Comment: $\sum_{n\ge}a_nz^n$ and $\sum_{n\ge}b_nz^n$ converge for $|z|_p<1$ but not $\sum_{n\ge}a_n$ and $\sum_{n\ge0}b_n$.

Comment: Ok, I understand your question now. I deleted my anwer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the answer is "not necessarily", by the following (counter)example. First, let $b_n=-a_n$ for $n\ge0$. Then $\sum(a_n+b_n)=0$ and 
$$f(z)=\sum_{n\ge0} a_n(1-z)z^n=\sum_{n\ge0} (a_n-a_{n-1})z^n,$$
where we set $a_{-1}=0$. Now, define
$$a_n:=\frac{-1}{n+1}.$$
Then, $\sum a_nz^n$ converges if and only if $|z|_p<1$. Also,
$$f(z)=\sum_{n\ge0}\frac{1}{n(n+1)}z^n,$$
which converges if and only if $|z|_p<1$.